# Find the sum of all the numbers divisible by 3 from the given N numbers. Pseudocode/Algorithm regarding loops

Tags: algorithm

As I analyzed it I have arrived on a conclusion but I don't think that its gonna work so I would appreciate if you correct it.
 If I want to enter a number again to be added on the sum variable what can be the decision ?

```
Start

Initialize
counter = 0 ,
sum = 0 

Input N 

N % 3 == 0 

If true , sum += N  then else if counter != N {
    If true , loop back to " Input N " 

    else print sum  
}
else , N not divisible by 3 .

Print sum 

End
```

Comment: *"from the given N numbers."* Which given N numbers?

Answer (score -1):

I assume you want sum of all numbers less than n and divisible by 3, try this

```
Input n
Initialize counter = 1, sum = 0
Do
    If counter % 3 == 0
        sum += counter
    counter++
While counter <= n
Print sum
```

Answer (score -3):

I can suggest you a faster algorithm
as our series would be 3,6,9,12,,15,21,24,27......3×n

The last digit which is divisible by 3 less than a given number N is N-1/3. Assign it to variable x.

```
for(int i =3; i<x;i+=3)
sum= sum + i
Print(sum)
```